# rails 3 custom mime type - default view format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, format, alias

I need to render some views without layout.
To skip line :render :layout=>false and if else logic from controller actions, 
i have custom mime type like phtml (plain html).

```
Mime::Type.register "text/phtml", :phtml
```

this format need to render the same html views, but only without layout. I complete this with this chunk of code in app. controller:

```
 before_filter proc { |controller|
  if params[:format] && params[:format]=='phtml'
    controller.action_has_layout = false
    controller.request.format    = 'html'

  end
  }
```

First, this is ugly, second i can't any more control this format from controller in the way:

```
respond_to :phtml,:only=>:index
```

because it will always render view with requested format phtml.
is there a better solution? example? how can i alias view formats?

Thank a lot

Comment: I've always thought `.phtml` was for PHP/PERL flavored HTML.

Comment: u are right. It can be .plain_html...it's not a point here...

Comment: I have this question too, I also need a way to render "plain html". There *must* be a good way to do this, as surely comes up a lot. I don't want to repeat all my controller actions (not very DRY). I don't know a good solution yet, but your information helped me, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the content-type, personally I still declare my custom extension as "text/html", as that's what it is – just with a different extension.  In the same way that ".htm" and ".html" are both "text/html".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `layout` method in your controller directly:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout "product", :except => [:index, :rss]
end
```

Or to use no layout at all:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout nil
end
```

Check out [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's not solution for me, because i need both situation in the same action (with or without layout). That is the reason why i need another format. This is useful for situation for example: printing, getting "plain" html from javascript etc...

Comment: `layout` accepts a proc as well, which would allow you to select the layout conditionally based on the requested format. Check out the guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info.

Comment: ok...it can solve layout problem. but it can't solve html format. it will still looking for phtml or(plain_html) templates. i need aproach for solving this problem. Finaly we still have a logic into layout proc block. :). I'm looking for a solution to override AppResponder < ActionController::Responder  with something like alias to_plain_html , to_html ...i will post solution if i get it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found better solution,only update to my previous example:

```
 before_filter proc { |controller|
    if params[:format] && params[:format]=='plain_html' && controller.collect_mimes_from_class_level.include?(:plain_html)
      controller.action_has_layout = false
      controller.request.format    = 'html'
    end
  }
```

i added this line to check is a new format defined into our controller:

```
controller.collect_mimes_from_class_level.include?(:plain_html)
```

Now we can have full new format which will render our standard html vews rather the build new views for the new format.

This can be useful if we wont to share existing html code, but build different logic based on requested format.

For example, we can easily prepare our html content  for print like:

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base

layout 'print',:only=>:show
respond_to :plain_html,:only=>[:show]

  def show
    Page.find(1)
    respond_with @page
  end
end
```

And request will be like:

```
http://www.example.com/pages/1.plain_html
```

I hope that someone will  find this useful.

If u have a better approach for doing this, please share with us.

Regards

Comment: This is pretty nice, but it doesn't work for me since I need to be able to render nested layouts. (Setting action_has_layout to false removes all layouts.)