# Where can I find documentation for the arguments passed to the block of the before_filter method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In another question here on stackoverflow ([rails 3 custom mime type - default view format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769058/rails-3-custom-mime-type-default-view-format)) another person used a rather interesting solution for rendering plain HTML. In his solution, he passed a block to the `before_filter` method and used methods such as `action_has_layout` to manipulate the object passed to the block. I checked the [official rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for these methods, but didn't find them. Would any of you happen to know where I can find the documentation for those methods? (Another, better answer for the question I referenced would be great too if you know of one.)

Here are some of the methods in question:

1. `controller.action_has_layout=`
2. `controller.request.format=`
3. `controller.collect_mimes_from_class_level`

I'd be grateful for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Layouts/action_has_layout%3F
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation/format%3D
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/collect_mimes_from_class_level

Comment: Ah, API dock; that's useful. Even there it looks like the documentation for those methods is pretty sparse, but it's certainly better than nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yeah, apidock is more complete than the official docs. As you noted, however, it doesn't necessarily matter ;) In general I've found that sometimes the only real way to get actual info is to *really* dig in to the source :( It's kind of a pain--but docs can always be added and submitted as pull requests.