# Ruby on Rails: Rendering a Page without the Application Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application, I'm trying to define a custom mime type that renders plain html without the site navigation or any formatting (css, etc). An answer to an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769058/rails-3-custom-mime-type-default-view-format) that I read described how to do this by turning off the layouts entirely for the current request, but **I want my rendered page to include nested layouts**, just not the main application layout. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `layout nil`  for no layout

```
layout 'name' for render your layout.
```

or you can use

```
render :layout => layout_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that also ignores nested layouts. I only want to ignore the application layout, without ignoring any other nested layouts.

Comment: you can specify layout "layout_name" in your action to render that layout.

Comment: But that's what I'm doing anyway. The problem is that these sub-layouts reference the main application layout so rendering them also renders the application layout. I'm trying to make rails ignore the application layout for this request.

Comment: May be this link helps you little about nested layouts http://m.onkey.org/nested-layouts-in-rails-3

Comment: Setting self.output_buffer looks like it could be a solution. I've just been using the method described in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) though.

Answer (score 0):

you can render any layout you wish, as in

render :layout => "special_nested_super_duper_layout"

ensure that the layout is located in app/views/layouts and you are good to go